# Correct use of would/used to/simple past

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

One of my friends went to a casino. His uncle happened to see him inside.  My friend got worried and told me about this:

> My Friend: My uncle saw me in the casino with John
>
> Me: What if he saw you in the casino? It doesn’t mean you were playing
>   there. you were just accompanying John.
>
> My Friend: I *would keep* John's coins on the table. My uncle saw it.
>   He thought I *would be playing*.

I think my friend didn't want to say just  a single action of keeping coin on the table but he wanted to say the repetitive action. Hence he said *I would keep John's.......*

Is the use of *I would keep......* correct in the context?

Answer (score 2):

Neither *would VERB* or *used to VERB* is appropriate here.

These constructions are employed to speak of actions which were habitual or repeated over a fairly long period of time.

> When we were living in Jersey John and I ***used to go*** to the casino every weekend; I never played myself, but I ***would keep*** John's chips for him.

In your example, however, your friend is speaking of what he was doing on a single occasion. He is describing what he was doing at the time his uncle saw him. Since that action—keeping John's coins—was already 'in progress' at the moment when his uncle saw him, he should employ the progressive construction, exactly as you do in the previous sentence:

> **You:** What if he did see you in the casino? —it doesn’t mean you ***were playing*** there. You ***were*** just ***accompanying*** John.
>
> **Your Friend:** I ***was keeping*** John's coins on the table. He saw that, and thought I ***was playing***.

However, it *is* possible for your friend to use *would* here in a different sense: to indicate that what his uncle saw and concluded is not something which your friend knows to be a fact but is something which your friend *infers* from the situation:

> **Your Friend:** I was keeping John's coins on the table. He ***would have seen*** that, and [***would have***] ***thought*** I was playing.

Note that this employs what I call the 'sham perfect' construction with the past-form modal + *have* + past participle. This is not a 'true' perfect but the perfect construction employed to mark past reference in a context which would otherwise be ambiguous.

Comment: In your last instance, is *would* the past form of *will*, signifying future in the past? Or, is it the tentative form of *will*, meaning "would be reasonable to conclude that ...'? To put it another way, in terms of perspectives, does *would* here indicate current orientation in the past (was keeping) or reference with hindsight to the past events (utterance)? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB It's a backshifted (tenseshifted) inferential *will*. The present-tense version would be "I'm keeping John's chips. Your uncle will have seen that, and will have thought that it was I who was playing, not John." The assertive present-tense version, without the inferential, would be "Your uncle saw that, and thought that it was I &c"

Comment: Ah, this is great. Is it possible to say "I'm keeping John's chips. My uncle *would have seen* that, and *would have thought* that it was I who was playing", where *would* could be regarded as the tentative form of *will*? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB  No; *would have* is past-referent. That sentence only works if the uncle passed through quite recently, within the 'current' timeframe throughout which you have held John's chips.